# using functions and while loops, how can i insert many fares into a list form. where the user can decide how many fares needs to be insert

Tags: python, function, while-loop, spyder

```
def get_fare(mini, maxi):

    fare = float(input("travel fare please: "))
    while fare not in range(mini, maxi+1):
        print("invalid value, please enter a new one") 
        fare = float(input("travel fare please: "))
    return fare

travel_fares = [get_fare(5,20), get_fare(5,20), get_fare(5,20)] # list of the functions 

average = sum(travel_fares)/len(travel_fares)

print (average)
```

I want to change this format where the user can input many fares instead 3. If I am to use list form, how can should I make the changes?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop or list comprehension.

```
how_many = int(input("How many fares?"))
travel_fares = [get_fare(5, 20) for _ in range(how_many)]
```